# ASP.net Cast FindControl output to a parameter

Tags: asp.net, casting, webforms, findcontrol, dynamic-controls

I want to cast the output of FindControl method to a control of a specific type but I want the type itself being passed as an argument. I first tried:

```
public static List<T> GetList<T>(..., Type tp, ...)
{
...
tp castedCtrl = (panel.FindControl(ctrlPrefixName + i.ToString()) as tp);
...
}
```

This is my preferred result but doesn't compile at all.
I also tried :

```
dynamic castedCtrl = Convert.ChangeType(panel.FindControl(ctrlPrefixName + i.ToString()), tp);
```

but this requires all my tp 's implement IConvertible interface which is not desired and required a lot of unintended work.

How can I cast the output of FindControl output to my desired type (which in action I want to pass the name of a user control class).

Comment: Does the type change frequently that you want to pass it as an argument every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public static List<T> GetList<T, U>(Page page, string ctrlPrefixName) 
   where T : class 
   where U : Control
{
   int i = 1;
   U castedCtrl = page.FindControl(ctrlPrefixName + i.ToString()) as U;
   return new List<T>();
}
```

In order to use it:

```
GetList<MyType, DropDownList>(this, "MyControl_");
```

Comment: Please consider T is a seperate class

Comment: T in my code actually represents that ascx's data object

Comment: So you can write where T : class and then you can use any class you want. But if you look for control your class will need to inherit from Control class anyway.

Comment: I want to pass type among arguments, T is used for a diffrent purpose (to pack that control's info in an object)

Comment: You cannot use type as variable, but you can add a second generic type to method declaration.

Comment: Thanks @Lesiman, This is the approach I also reached and truly works